# Given matrices $A,B,C$ such that $BC=A$ find $\det(CB)$ and $\operatorname{Tr}(CB)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2&-2 & 3\\ 0&0&3 \\ 0&0&3 \\ \end{pmatrix}$. $B$ is a $3\times 2$ matrix and $C$ is a $2 \times 3$ matrix such that $BC=A$. Find $\det(CB)$ and $\operatorname{Tr}(CB)$.

I read this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3546335/matrices-given-ab-how-to-find-determinant-of-ba) but i have not learned about characteristic polynomials yet and the answer that does not use those is tedious.

I also read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782600/when-a-and-b-are-of-different-order-given-the-detab-then-calculate-detba) but in my case it is the other way around, i know the determinant which equals $0$, but i do not know how to find the "other one".

Also, I am not that familiar with spaces and dimensions in linear algebra so i would prefer a solution that does not involve deep knowledge in this area.

Any tips ?

Comment: The trace side of this is actually simple: So long as $AB$ is a square matrix, then $\operatorname{Tr}(AB)=\operatorname{Tr}(BA)$. No other properties of $A,B$ are needed.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ has rank $2$, $B$ has full column rank. It follows that if $Av=BCv=0$ for some vector $v$, we must have $Cv=0$.

Now let $v=(1,1,0)^T$. Then $Av=0$. Hence $Cv=0$. Let $u=(0,1,0)^T$. Then $u^Tv=1$. Therefore
\begin{aligned}
\det(CB)
&=\det\pmatrix{CB&0\\ \ast&1}\\
&=\det\left[\pmatrix{C\\ u^T}\pmatrix{B&v}\right]\\
&=\det\left[\pmatrix{B&v}\pmatrix{C\\ u^T}\right]\\
&=\det(A+vu^T)\\
&=\det\pmatrix{2&-1&3\\ 0&1&3\\ 0&0&3}=6.
\end{aligned}
Finally, as the trace of a product of matrices is invariant under cyclic permutation of the multiplicands, we have $\operatorname{tr}(CB)=\operatorname{tr}(BC)=\operatorname{tr}(A)=5$.

Answer (score 0):

A practical approach is to simply find suitable matrices $B$ and $C$ for which $BC = A$. If the question is well formulated, then it suffices to compute the trace and determinant of $CB$ for our particular choice of matrices $C$ and $B$.

To that end: we can take $B$ to be the matrix
$$
B = \pmatrix{1 & 1\\0&1\\0&1}
$$
because each column of $A$ is a multiple of one of these columns. With that in mind, we can take
$$
C = \pmatrix{2&-2&0\\0&0&3}.
$$
Verify that we indeed have $BC = A$. With that, we now compute
$$
CB = \pmatrix{2&-2&0\\0&0&3}\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1\\0&1} = \pmatrix{2&0\\0&3}.
$$
It is easy to compute the determinant $2 \cdot 3 = 6$ and the trace $2 + 3 = 5$.